# Replacing placeholders in Email Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

What is the better way to replace placeholders in email module?

So, I have made a mail service which takes parameters like `templatename` , `receiverMail` & `locals`. locals have the values for placeholders.

```
var locals = {
    username: "John",
    website: "w3schools.com",
    url: "http:// abc. com"
};

mail.sendMail('Registration', 'xyz.com', locals);
```

Relevant Code from Mail service :-

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: "Abc <foo@blurdybloop.com>", // sender address
        to: email, // list of receivers
        subject: template_subject, // Subject line
        html: template_html // html body
```

`template_html` contents the html body including the `placeholders` this is pulled from mongodb.

The `locals` are dynamic & can be increased or decreased.

What is the way to replace the placeholders?

Template:- (pls note these placeholders are dynamic & can be changed by admin)

```
<p>
    Hi {{username}},
</p>
<p>
   Xyz would like you to join it's network on <a href="{{url}}">xyz</a>.
    <br />
    Our website {{ website }}
</p>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample of the `template_html` string with the actual placeholders?

Comment: @BlakeSimpson yes sure...i included a template

Comment: I would use the answer from Basha. His script will do the job, just replace "<%=" with "{{" and "%>" with "}}".

Answer (score 2):

We can use regular expressions to search and replace the template with the user specified data.

I have put up a small demo at

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5RycL/1/)

Here I am replacing the template with the actual data.

I am using the below code for replacing the data in the template:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        output +="<p>" + template.replace(/\<%=(.*?)\%>/g, function(match, property) {
            return obj[property];
        }) + "</p>";

 }
```

Comment: I used ur code, but getting error :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594292/error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop

Comment: Hi @Anup, I have answered your questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594292/error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop

Comment: i replaced ur new fiddle code, but i have some issues

Answer (score 0):

In this function replace all the tags with the values from the object passed in the parameter using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

In this example use **{{key}}** in my html template

```js
function replaceTemplateValues(template, values){
    let html = template;
    for (let key in values) {
        html = html.replace(new RegExp('{{' + key + '}}', 'g'), values[key]);
    }
    return html;
}
```