# Error - Don't make functions within a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am trying to replace placeholders in a email template, Following is my code:-

I am getting the `error : Don't make functions within a loop`

```
var dataPlaceholders = [{
            "username":"John Johny",
            "website":"w3schools . com"
            }];

template_html = "<b>Hello <%= username %>,</b><br/><br/> You are successfuly Registered on xyz.<br/><br/>Thank you <%= website %>";
```

function call :-

```
function ReplacePlaceholders(dataPlaceholders, template_html){
    for (var i = 0; i < dataPlaceholders.length; i++) {
        var obj = dataPlaceholders[i];
        template_html += "" + template_html.replace("/<%=%>/g", function (match, property) {
            return obj[property];
        }) + "";

    }
    return template_html;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: For help you with *what*? The error message clearly states what's wrong

Comment: @Zerkms i got 1 new `error` : After creating a new function....`error : missing new prefix when invoking a constructor`

Comment: do you know what http://google.com is?

Comment: @zerkms i am in absolute hurry... if u don't want to help...leave the question....i am beginner to `node.js`

Comment: being in hurry doesn't justify laziness, sorry.

Comment: Its poor practice to make just about any declaration in a loop unless you MUST. Declarations take time and memory, especially functions, arrays and objects.

Answer (score 3):

From [JSLint Error Explanations](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/):

> The fundamental problem here is that the JavaScript interpreter will create an instance of the function per loop iteration. It has to do this because it doesn't know if the function object will be modified elsewhere. Since functions are standard JavaScript objects, they can have properties like any other object, which could be changed in the loop. Thus by creating the function in the loop context, you cause the interpreter to create multiple function instances, which can cause unexpected behavior and performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you are creating a function variable inside a loop:  `function (match, property)`

This would mean that if you had 100 elements in your loop it would create 100 anonymous functions which is not good for performance.

To resolve this move the function declaration outside your for loop. So your code becomes something like this

```
function ReplacePlaceholders(dataPlaceholders, template_html){
    // here we create a single instance of your match function
    var match = function (match, property) {
        return obj[property];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dataPlaceholders.length; i++) {
        var obj = dataPlaceholders[i];

        // now we use our single declared instance inside the for loop
        template_html += "" + template_html.replace("/<%=%>/g", match) + "";
    }
    return template_html;
}
```

Comment: Yes i did this...but placeholders aren't replaced in my mail...wt might be the issue?

Comment: @Anup Can't help sorry. There are too many things we don't know. Post another question with information on what is in `dataPlaceholders` and  `template_html`